# Accessing smb share on Trimble YUMA with python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, python-2.6

I need to write a script that would import a .shp on the YUMA to a gdb on the script/host pc for manipulation with arcpy. I can't seem to find a smb python module. So Im not entirely sure on how to do this.

Have I just not found it? surly its came up before.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is. ftputil and a filezilla server on the YUMA. But I'd rather go the smb route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You theoretically shouldn't need any special SMB module to copy files from one Windows PC to another. You can just use [shutil](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/shutil.html) and/or [CopyFeatures](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000.htm) and the `\\machine\directory` style path to copy to or set the share up as a network drive and copy it to `Z:` or whatever letter you wind up giving it. You could also [refer to this solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228846/python-authentication-to-samba-share) if you need to authenticate against the network share at run time as well.